# Unknown hijacker/popups on the browser

Tags: attacks, attack-prevention, virus

I was cleaning my father’s laptop which was recently infected by a fairly tenacious piece of malware.  It hasn't given any great clues as to what it is named or anything of that sort and thus far resisted me try most of the techniques. Some of the symptoms of the virus are:

- Popups while using some Adcash sites.
- Hijacking attempts to navigate to pages.
- Slow browser

What could be the virus and how do I remove it?

Comment: You are not going to get any advise except for reinstalling the operating system. That may not even be enough, but certainly trying to remove it from the infected system itself is not ideal.

Answer (score 7):

Salvage data you wish to keep (but keep in mind something may be infected so analyse backup later), format hard drive, reinstall the OS.

It's the only way.

Answer (score 2):

What browser does he use? I've had users that have experienced similar issues, and one of the first places I check is the extensions running on all installed browsers. You can find pretty good clues as to the name of the program you need to remove in order to stop the pop-ups.

Check his installed programs for anything that might be out of place too. If my users don't recognize something or it looks suspicious, I usually Google search it to get more info. That's a pretty useful method for me as well. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Reformat your computer and re-install your operating system. More importantly, secure a copy of an antivirus and update it regularly.